# How do I list the files associated with a Python package installed using pip or easy_install?

Tags: python, pip

I've installed a Python package using pip, which is a replacement for easy_install. How do I get a list of which installed files are associated with this package?

Basically, I'm looking for the Python package equivalent of

```
dpkg -L
```

or

```
rpm -ql
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You could do that by using command:

```
pip show -f <package>
```

Comment: Does not work for me, `pip: error: No command by the name pip show`. (Using pip 1.1)

Comment: @Zitrax Well, currently I am using pip 1.4.1, and it works, may be you should upgrade pip.

Comment: Yes, here is the answer to that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14060138/816449

It works in 1.2.1.post1.

Comment: It appears this doesn't work for every package.  E.g. `pip show -f nbconvert` gives `Files: Cannot locate installed-files.txt`.

Comment: It also doesn't work for packages installed using `python setup.py develop`.

Answer (score 6):

Two years later, most pip instances have show, however, not all packages have the installed-files.txt program for the subcommand to read.

A workaround is to fire up the python shell and do this:

```
>>> import eventlet
>>> eventlet.__path__
    ['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet']
```

where "eventlet" is the package I installed with pip.

Answer (score 4):

I use virtualenv with pip, so here are the steps I follow. Assume I'm working in the `dave_venv` virtual environment.

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc

export WORKON_HOME=/usr/local/virtualenvs

$ cd /usr/local/virtualenvs/dave_venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
$ ls # This should show <your_package>.
$ cd <your_package>
$ ls # now you're looking at your package's files.
```

Comment: works in most cases, but not if the package installs any command-line scripts, which would end up in usr/local/bin....  also, some packages may install multiple modules...

Comment: @hwjp Do you know the answer to: [Find which python package owns a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55864568/find-which-python-conda-package-owns-a-binary)?